# Set cover background to always start from top of image?

Tags: html, image, css

My ultimate goal is to have a block of text in a fixed position relative to a background image.

But what seems to be preventing this is that when I resize the browser, the image stays the same size like I want, but the image shifts -- i.e., the top of the image rendered isn't always the top of the image source.

Here's a mockup - imagine that I want the block of text to be in the blue box:

http://jsfiddle.net/rrauenza/9hkn8p4e/embedded/result/

The yellow "ceiling" in this picture sometimes disappears for different browser sizes.

```
<head><style>
.intro-header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background: url(http://c3softworks.com/demos/images/backgrounds_04.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    height: 700px;
}
.intro-message {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    height: 700px;
}
</style></head>

<div class="intro-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="intro-message">
                     <h1>Title</h1>

                     <h3>...subtitle</h3>

                    <hr class="intro-divider">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-3">
                         <h4>Something</h4>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2">
                         <h4>Something Else</h4>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
background-size: cover;
```

If you're counting on the background image not to scale it might help not to ask it to.

Also, in your fiddle `.intro-header` has a `background-position:center bottom`, while here you post `center top`. It needs to be `center top` of course.

Comment: I will try it.  What is confusing is my problem didn't seem like a scaling problem.  The image didn't scale -- it only shifted.